# How to you only allow admins to set admin privileges?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, ruby-on-rails-4, authentication, activerecord

If I set up a basic `User` model in Rails, and give it an `is_admin:boolean, default: false` attribute, what's the best way to prevent non-admin users from changing this?

It seems like the sort of logic that should really go into the model, but what's the best way to construct it? ActiveRecord callback functions?

I know I could put this into the controller's `#update` method, but that doesn't seem to match MVC best practices. (And seems less portable.)

What's the best approach here?

Comment: For additional context, assume I'm following this tutorial exactly: http://railscasts.com/episodes/270-authentication-in-rails-3-1?view=asciicast

Answer (score 1):

Denying access with a redirect is a job perfect for a controller, so doing it in private before_filter method would be sufficient and justified in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you say that the logic should go in the model?

It depends on your implementation. If the logic is dependent on the `current_user` (i.e. can a current admin set another user to be an admin as well), then the logic should go in the controller. Since you tagged the question as Rails 4, the logic will go in the permitted params in your controller:

```
def user_params
  if current_user.is_admin
    params.require(:user).permit(...your attributes here with is_admin...)
  else
    params.require(:user).permit(...your attributes here without is_admin...)
  end
end
```

Comment: I was thinking it should go in the model, so that the db integrity isn't dependent on the controller. That is, it's the model that should enforce proper db update logic. I guess the admin property would only ever be changed through the controller?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "so that the db integrity isn't dependent on the controller", but your whole app is dependent on the controller, so in a way your db is dependent on the controller. In this case, your controller is not responsible for updating the record, but responsible for what is passed to the model, and then the model updates the record based on what was passed to it.

Comment: Makes sense. Does Rails tends to have fatter controllers in general? At this point, all my logic is controller-side, and nothing is really in the model. From what I remember of my Java days, (which were long ago,) we learned to put as much as possible into the model, and that it should never allow an incorrect action. In this case, allowing the user to be updated without validating that it's an admin explicitly doing the updating. Does rails not follow that rule of thumb so much?

Comment: Rails does follow the skinny controllers - fat model convention. As you didn't share your controller logic, I cannot comment on why you have a lot of logic in your controller. Controllers usually act as passing information from the view to the model, in this case the information passed from the view to the model is dependent on whether the user is admin or not. A great example of what the controller should look like is when you run `rails g scaffold SomeModel`

Answer (score 1):

I would set admin privileges only in the console like that:

```
a = User.find_by(email: "user@example.com")
a.toggle!(:admin)
```

You would prevent somebody cracking into your site to gain admin privileges.

Comment: Thanks -- I think this is what I'll end up going with for now.